# Collect exp. Function with distinct Values in Mapping Data Flow ADF Aggregate Transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataflow, collect

I want to use collect(column1) function that collects all row values for a group By column2 in Agg. Transformation. But since that column1 has duplicates values, I get duplicates in my returned array. I want a function that collects all distinct values.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no collectDistinct() function so you cant achieve this by function in dataflow.

You can try this:
create two Aggregate Transformation.

First,group by base model number and modelDocId,then add a column(DModelDocId) and expression is `first(modelDocId)`.

Second,group by base model number，then add a column(modelDocIds) and expression is `collect(DModelDocId)`.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Steve. That did solve my problem. I have another problem about dynamic json objects as mapping data flow does not allow me to  provide json key value as variable or create it from modifying a value. I have it in another question. Please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered, but there is easier way to collect unique values in aggregate situations like this, without needing another group by. In our scenario, we had the data as follows

| ORDER_NO | BRAND          |

| -------- | -------------- |

| ORD001   | ExampleBrand1  |

| ORD001   | ExampleBrand1  |

| ORD001   | ExampleBrand2  |

We wanted to get this to one row per ORDER_NO, with unique brands listed against it. Sample output as follows

| ORDER_NO | BRANDS |

| -------- | -------------- |

| ORD001   | ExampleBrand1,ExampleBrand2 |

So we did add an aggregate transformation (group by) on ORDER_NO, and used collect(BRAND) to collect all BRAND values in an array named BRANDS_ARR.

After this, we added a Derived Column transformation, and converted the array of BRAND strings to unique string BRANDS as follows

column name: BRANDS

Expression:
`toString(reduce(BRANDS_ARR, '', iif((instr(#acc, #item) > 0), #acc, #acc + #item + ',') , #result))`

Note that we use reduce function with iif and instr functions to decide if the next value should be accumulated or not. This way duplicates get filtered and you get a "Set" like functionality.

Nit: Above snippet gets an extra comma in the end, which can easily be stripped off using replace function.